# Why does calling lua_newuserdata result in SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, lua, gdb, luajit, lua-api

I'm trying to identify why a call to lua_newuserdata result in SIGSEGV. The gdb backtrace is :

```
Thread 2 "main.o" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7c1a700 (LWP 41635)]
0x0000555555573bbe in sweepstep.constprop ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000555555573bbe in sweepstep.constprop ()
#1  0x000055555557531c in singlestep ()
#2  0x0000555555575d22 in luaC_step ()
#3  0x000055555556fbb7 in lua_newuserdatauv ()
```

To give some scope, this particular call works on numerous invocations -- it only yields this result when I have an io.popen call inside a lua script that runs a process that takes longer to complete than the lifecycle of the lua thread (coroutine) that spawns it.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I wonder if stopping the GC with lua_gc(L, GCSTOP)/lua_gc(L, GCRESTART) around the creation of a new lua thread (coroutine) and it's associative offending lua_newuserdata call might help.

EDIT: (apologies for the long code) The repo SIGFAULTs on lua_pushlstring:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"

    #define NT 18 //it works with a lower value

    struct stream_data {
    int fd;
    int len;
    int idx;
    char buf[128];
    };

    struct stream {
       lua_State *L;
       lua_State *T;
       struct stream_data *strm_d;
       int id;
       int status;
       char buf[128];
    };

    static lua_State *L;
    static int active = 0;
    static int fref;

    struct stream *new_strm(lua_State *L, int i) {
        struct stream *strm;
        lua_State *T;
        char str[64];
        int na;

        snprintf(str, 64, "thread id: %i", i);
        T = lua_newthread(L);

        lua_pushlightuserdata(L, T);
        strm = (struct stream *) lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(struct stream));
        lua_rawset(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
        lua_pop(L, 1);

        lua_rawgeti(T, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, fref);
        lua_pushstring(T, str);

        strm->id = i;
        strm->T = T;
        strm->L = L;

        strm->status = lua_resume(T, L, 1, &na);

        return strm;
    }

    static int register_fn(lua_State *L) {
        fref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
        return 0;
    }

    int lua_read(lua_State *L) {
        struct stream *strm;
        struct stream_data *strm_d;
        void *sd;
        FILE *f;

        lua_pushlightuserdata(L, L);
        lua_rawget(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
        strm = (struct stream*) lua_touserdata(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);

        sd = (void*) lua_touserdata(L, 1);
        f = *(FILE**) luaL_checkudata(L, 1, LUA_FILEHANDLE);

        lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*) sd);
        strm_d = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(struct stream_data));
        lua_rawset(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

        strm_d->len = lua_tointeger(L, 2);
        strm_d->idx = 0;
        strm_d->fd = fileno(f);
        strm->strm_d = strm_d;

        return lua_yield(L, 0);
    }

    int do_read(struct stream *strm) {
        struct stream_data *strm_d = strm->strm_d;
        int na, rv;

        if ((rv = read(strm_d->fd, &strm_d->buf, strm_d->len - strm_d->idx)) >= 0) {
            strm_d->idx += rv;
            if (strm_d->idx >= strm_d->len) {
                lua_pushlstring(strm->T, strm_d->buf, strm_d->len);
                strm->status = lua_resume(strm->T, strm->L, 1, &na);
            }
        }
        return 0;

    }

    static int luaopen_app(lua_State *L) {
        struct luaL_Reg functions[] = {
            { "register_fn",    register_fn},
            { "read",       lua_read },
        { NULL, NULL }
        };
        luaL_newlib(L, functions);
        return 1;
    }

lua_State* app_init() {
    L = luaL_newstate();

    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_app);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "app");
    lua_pop(L, 2);

    luaL_loadfile(L, "script.lua");
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

    return L;
}

int main() {
    L = app_init();

    struct stream *strm[NT];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NT; i++) {
        strm[i] = new_strm(L, i);
    }

    while (1) {
        int done = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < NT; i++) {
            if (strm[i]->status == 1) {
                do_read(strm[i]);
                done = 0;
            } else {
                lua_gc(L, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
                done = 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
          if (done == 1)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

###### script.lua

```
app = require 'app'

local function foo(txt)
    print(txt)

    local F = assert(io.popen('sh ./script.sh 2', 'r'))

    local g = app.read(F, 5)
    print(txt..' read: '..g)

    print('done')
end

app.register_fn(foo)
```

###### script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 $1
sleep 14
echo 2 $1
echo 3 $1
echo 4 $1
echo 5 $1
```

Comment: You might want to add the related C code, with only this backtrace it's difficult to help.

Comment: You're still missing loads of essential parts of the code. Minimal verifiable sample please?

Comment: `io.popen call inside a lua script that runs a process that takes longer to complete than the lifecycle of the lua thread` - The nearest GC invocation will hang (possibly forever) waiting until the `io.popen`-started process is finished.  Actually, the waiting happens inside `close()` method of the object returned by `io.popen`.  Probably your program interferes with this somehow.  Please make a short code to reproduce the crash behavior.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that's spot on, an earlier version was behaving exactly like you describe - it would hang until the io.popen finished. Is there a way to cleanup the coroutine from C and resume execution immediately without the hang and discard whatever io.popen has to finish? In the meantime I'll work on an example.

Comment: `an earlier version was behaving exactly like you describe - it would hang until the io.popen finished` - AFAIK, this does not depend on Lua version.  The `process:close()` call is just a wrap-around for a function from C library.  That's why I am unable to reproduce your problem on my home PC.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff i think an important detail is that the lua script does not call io.popen. I don’t want that detail to lead to a SIGFAULT or have to block the main lua state waiting around just to discard whatever the opened process does after the coroutine finishes execution.

Comment: You can not close the coroutine without closing all subprocesses.  Just anchor the coroutine in a global variable to avoid it being GC-ed.

Comment: `an important detail is that the lua script does not call io.popen` - This contradicts to what you have written in the question.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff My mistake, I meant to say io.close in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, `close` is invoked automatically when GC collects the coroutine.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I added a minimal verifiable sample. It works with a lower NT value. Notice the lua script deliberately has no corresponding close for the popen, and it SEGAULTS on lua_pushlstring.

Comment: You have tagged your question as `luajit` but you are using Lua 5.4 version of `lua_resume` in your C code.  What is your Lua version?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think I figured it out. Popping the lua thread (T) from the main lua state stack (L) results in SIGFAULTs down the road, even if I have a reference of it in the registry. It behaves similar on lua and luajit.